# MS Access sql error query

Tags: sql, ms-access

MY Code

```
SELECT JuvCourt.ID, 
       JuvCourt.Category, 
       JuvCourt.Decision, 
       JuvCourt.intake_participant_role_code, 
       JuvCourt.[Screen In Date],JuvCourt.IDX, 
       JuvCourt.intake_type_code, JuvCourt.sex, 
       JuvCourt.RACE, JuvCourt.AGEFROM JuvCourt 
Where JuvCourt.Category LIKE *" & searhtxt & "*"
```

Gives me synyax error (missing operator) ...error 3075

Answer (score 0):

```
JuvCourt.AGEFROM JuvCourt
```

needs a space to become

```
JuvCourt.AGE FROM JuvCourt
```

and replace

```
*" & searhtxt & "*"
```

with

```
'%" & searhtxt & "%'"
```

Comment: JuvCourt.Category LIKE ' "*" & searhtxt & "*" ' "

Comment: Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

    Dim searchsql As String
     Dim searchtxt As String
         
         searchtxt = Me.txtSearch
         
         searchsql = "SELECT JuvCourt.ID, JuvCourt.Category, JuvCourt.Decision, JuvCourt.intake_participant_role_code, JuvCourt.[Screen In Date],JuvCourt.IDX, JuvCourt.intake_type_code, JuvCourt.sex, JuvCourt.RACE, JuvCourt.AGE FROM JuvCourt Where JuvCourt.Category LIKE "%" & 'searchtxt' & "%" "
                     
         Me.SubJuvCourt.Form.RecordSource = searchsql
         Me.SubJuvCourt.Form.Requery
         
         
 End Sub

Comment: You know the difference between single and double quotes?

Comment: I am trying various combinations...here is a simple code same error ..........                                                                                                 Private Sub cboGender_Change()
Dim qGender As String
qGender = "Select * from JuvCourt where ([sex] = '" & Me.cboGender & "')"
Me.JuvCrt_Subfrm.Form.RecordSource = qGender
Me.JuvCrt_Subfrm.Form.Requery
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You miss a space before the from

```
AGEFROM JuvCourt
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `where` condition to

```
Where JuvCourt.Category LIKE "*" & searhtxt & "*" --double-quote missing previously
```

as a `double-quote` is missing around `*`.

Comment: that was okay @JuanCarlosOropeza..but the `where` condition was missing a `"` after `like`.